# CoreMLTools convert causes "Error reading protobuf spec. validator error"

Tags: tensorflow, keras, coremltools, transfer-learning

I have been working on building a custom convolutional network, which has been saved into .h5 file. Further one I've applied transfer learning by popping the last layers (FC) ones, and then compiling the model with the new data. Again saved the model in .h5 format.
The problem occurs when I try to convert this model to mlModel format. I get the following error:

```
return _MLModelProxy(filename)
RuntimeError: Error compiling model: "Error reading protobuf spec. validator error: Layer 'conv2d_2__activation__' consumes a layer named 'conv2d_2__activation___output' which is not present in this network."
```

I am freezing the layers of the original convolutional neural network. 
The versions I'm using are:

- Keras (2.1.6)
- Protobuf(3.6.0)
- Tensorflow(1.8.0)

For the conversion :

```
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(
    pathToh5File,
    class_labels=['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
)
```

I've tried adding input names and so on. Still getting the same result.

I would be grateful for any suggestion.
Thank you in advance!